# getting error when trying to do ajax from outside folder

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a file under webroot folder out of cakephp default installation and I want to get a json response back. But when I try to do that I get this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.com/companies/all_company_information. Origin http://dev.local is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
 $.ajax({

         type: 'POST',
         url: '/controller/method',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){

             console.log(data);

         }

     });
```

I have read up on some of the info on google but I think I am not understanding this.

**EDIT**

when I use jsonp I get this error

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:

$.ajax({

```
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/controller/method',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success: function(data){

             console.log(data);

         }

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a function in an appropriate controller that is setup to respond with the intended json.  A controller configured to respond with json:

```
function feed($date){
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->autoLayout = false;
$data = $this->Model->find();
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I use the firefox extension firebug heavily in order to ensure my ajax requests are going through and what their responses are.